# about jw player and how to move logo

Tags: edit, jwplayer

i have problem with jw player ver 6

i already have ver 6 enterprise so i add logo to player but i want move logo to close to bottom but only in jw settings

```
logo: {
                file: '{$siteurl}/player/logo.png',
                link: '{$siteurl}',
                position: 'bottom-right',
                hide: 'false',
                margin: '10',
                linktarget: '_blank',
                hide: 'false',
                over: '1',
                out: '1'
                },
```

so how to move logo to end of bottom

example

[image: http://www.elfnoon.com/demo/kleeja/uploads/1385529652271.gif]

so how guys?

Comment: You can move it to the bottom right, but not to overlap the YouTube logo.

Comment: thx bro but any way to get video from google video with youtube video id to hide youtube logo < sorry but want hide youtube logo with anyway

Comment: No there is not. That is illegal.

Comment: if that , any other way to stop youtube link from work? or that tow illegal??

Comment: It is illegal to stop their link too. YouTube isn't like some free video hosting service. They require their logo and link back to them via their API to be compliant with their TOS.

Comment: and if i move logo to be absolute of youtube logo then what can youtube company do? cuz i do it not in localhost but not know what youtube company do if know that? and i try add related videos but not work and im sure xml file work good but icon of related now show , why that? and thx for help me brother

Comment: I am not endorsing covering up their logo. End of case.

Answer (score 0):

to hide youtube logo i use this settings

```
logo: {
                file: '{$siteurl}/player/logo.png',
                link: '{$siteurl}',
                position: 'bottom.right',
                hide: 'false',
                margin: '-35',
                linktarget: '_blank',
                hide: 'false',
                over: '10',
                out: '0.75'
                },
```

and your logo width:96px height:37px

and full png logo width 150 and height 65
and logo file need to be png format and only your logo with any color of background and start your logo from right of png file 39px and top 24px and you will see logo of youtube will be hide ;)

example

http://www.elfnoon.com/demo/kleeja/uploads/1385582222521.png

hope i help who want ask

Answer (score 0):

just edit `plugins/content/jw_allvideos/jw_allvideos/tmpl/Responsive/css/template.css`

and  add this css style.

```
.jwlogo {
     margin: -35000px;
     display:none;
}
```

This worked for me.